# I tried looking online, but doesn't specify what follows "git push "

Tags: git, github, terminal, command

I'm using github to get some code up. However, I'm having trouble with the git commands. To be clear, once I am on my folder, to push it to my repo and branch. I used:

```
git add . 
git commit -m "changed xyz" 
git push (name of branch?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one just follows it with a remote and a branch:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
```

If you cloned it from your own github repo, then the remote you want is likely `origin` and the branch you want is likely `master`, i.e.

```
git push origin master
```

The full range of options can be seen with

```
git push --help
```